# Why can I not import this module that is clearly here?

Tags: python, importerror

I just got a module(setuptools), but I'm using it locally (not installing it into Python's libs). The problem is, python can't seem to recognize it as a module

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/James/beep/setup.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tools import setup
ImportError: No module named tools
```

My hierarchy:

```
folder-------|
             |-other stuff
             |
             |-setuptools folder
             |
             |-setup.py
             |
             |-main section of my app
```

Comment: You have a setup.py file, no tools.py. "from x import y" will look for "x.py" and import class/function/variable "y" from x.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your module is named tools, you likely need a `__init__.py` file within this folder in order for it to be recognized as a module.

This can be an empty file, but it must be present. See: http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html

Comment: No actually, without it you can still use your .py files as module. Every py file is a module.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is,your folder name is *setup.py*. Change it and try again, you know as an experienced Python programmer, every program is a module if it's a *.py* file.So maybe there is another files with same name as your module and Python cant understand. Also if your module name is *setuptools* you should use

```
from setuptools import *
```

Not;

```
from tools import setup
```

Your question is very complicated, you said you have a module named *setuptools* , you coding */Users/James/beep/setup.py* and you trying to import *from tools import setup*. Hard to understand what are you doing actually.

Comment: The module is a folder.

Comment: Folders are not modules, they are folders. If you have a file .py its a module.Also as I said, try to make a .py file in desktop and open another one, import a function from that .py folder. You dont have to use init.py for modules as you can see with this little test.You just have to find correct direction and show it to Python,thats it.

Comment: Or package, whatever you wanna call it.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the tools module located? Is it in your PYTHONPATH or in the root folder of this project? I don't see any module or package named "tools" in your folder listing

If you wish to create a setup.py file, it should look like this:

```
from setuptools import setup
```

Instead of this:

```
from tools import setup
```